# Generate collection of pairs/triplets in R

Tags: r

I'm generating pairs of objects from a vector, and there may be a triplet if the vector is of odd length.  How can I store these and keep them as pairs/triplets?  The pairs are vectors.  I've tried adding to a vector like

```
vect <- c(vect, pair)
```

but it flattens all the pairs in the vector.  I also tried appending to a list with `list <- list(list, pair)` and `list <- list(list, list(pair))`, as well as `list.append()` from `rlist` but none of that seems to work well.

Comment: This isn't clear. Maybe you want to give an example.

Comment: I don't understand the triplet requirement.  Anyway, a list of vectors would seem to be one way to represent your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `split`   you just need to give it a vector that says how you want to split the array.

```
ARRAY = 1:13
SF = rep(1:(length(ARRAY)/2), each=2) 
if(length(SF) < length(ARRAY)) { SF = c(SF, SF[length(SF)]) }
split(ARRAY, SF)

$`1`
[1] 1 2

$`2`
[1] 3 4

$`3`
[1] 5 6

$`4`
[1] 7 8

$`5`
[1]  9 10

$`6`
[1] 11 12 13
```